# Is there an R function for deriving digits?

Tags: r, digits, number-theory

I have seen the solution in the past but forgot where: is there an R function that turns x=1234 into its digits (1,2,3,4) and vice-versa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a <- c("1234")
res <- strsplit(a,"")
res
#[[1]]
#[1] "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

Note that if `a` is a numeric vector, you should cast it as a character string first. You can recast the result back to numeric later if you need to. The following command does this for you so long as you left `res` in the list form it was originally returned as.

```
lapply(res,as.numeric)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

`res` will contain a list with one item per input string with each character assigned to its own element in a vector. In this case, there is just one input string, and therefore just one list item (which contains a vector) in the output.

The reverse operation can be done with the `paste()` function:

```
a<-c(5,2,8,0)
paste(a,collapse="")
```

You may want to wrap the `paste` up in `as.numeric()`

Comment: Thank you for a prompt answer!

Comment: To do the reverse, use `paste0`

Comment: ... `paste0` with `collapse = ""`.

Comment: @Xi'an woops! I totally missed the "and vice-versa." See updated answer. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another possibility:

```
x <- 1234
as.numeric(sapply(sequence(nchar(x)), function(y) substr(x, y, y)))
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```

`nchar` tells us how many characters long the "string" is. Wrapping that in `sequence` generates the positions we need for `substr`. `substr` will automatically convert your input to `character` before extracting based on the start and end position.